# Non-english objects' name

Tags: support

I'd like to ask a question about a performance issue I'm facing. However my application was built in Portuguese, so my table and columns names are in Portuguese.

Should I translate the tables and columns names on the code sample? I can do that, however it may be necessary post an entire table create statement in order to people help me.

So how to deal with that?

Comment: no need to translate the column names, just making clear what's the logic behind your code is enough

Comment: It would probably still be more readable than SAP table names

Answer (score 7):

We gladly accept questions that are in English, even if the code isn't. The keywords for the language in question will almost always be in English, and if it isn't, we can probably find someone to help.

Most variable and column/table names are symbolic logic when you strip things away (that's why examples always use A, B, C etc) so we have gotten pretty used to figuring out how to drop that.

Give us schema and any documentation that you think we need to understand the problem and we'll usually take it.

Credit to Lamak for being faster than me ;-)

Comment: Debit to Lamak for answering in the wrong box though :)